# iMacros can't record drop down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, imacros

I'm trying to record a drop down menu from this one website. When I clicked the drop down button and choose one of the content then I can only see this code.

```
TAG POS=10 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:-<SP>Please<SP>select<SP>-
```

Is there anything I can do to record and choose a value inside the drop down menu?

Full code :

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://mycoid2016.ssm.com.my/Zukami/fillform.aspx?ListID=45be40d2-f162-4093-85e1-c05bd6a3d809&ParentRec=a3dd4baa-5238-477d-aa51-c6be6e2e2f2c&a=2e9d5b97-691b-4164-859d-ceb25cf5bf8e&New=1
TAG POS=10 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:-<SP>Please<SP>select<SP>-
```

Comment: I guess that 'Experimental event recording mode' should be helpful to you.

Comment: Yep, somehow that's the solution, worked well for me. Thanks!